# Is this implementation of a bcrypt EtM flawed?

Tags: encryption, authentication, hash, bcrypt

`I know that you should never roll your own crypto, but I'm just implementing/combining(?) two highly trusted algorithms into Javascript`

First, I am using a bcrypt implementation that I did not code.
Secondly, I can switch hashing algorithms if bcrypt is not suitable for an EtM approach.
[According to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Approaches_to_authenticated_encryption) EtM is: `The plaintext is first encrypted, then a MAC is produced based on the resulting ciphertext. The ciphertext and its MAC are sent together. Used in, e.g., IPsec. The standard method according to ISO/IEC 19772:2009. This is the only method which can reach the highest definition of security in AE, but this can only be achieved when the MAC used is "strongly unforgeable".`
So, I am trying to use bcrypt as the proper hash function used to create the message authentication code. Now, I need to know if this exact implementation of the EtM is secure. Distribution of secret keys are not in my control (e.g. not my responsibility here) Also, I did make sure that the encryption key and authentication key are different. This is the code of the *receiver's* side:

```
function authenticate() {
         var authentication = document.getElementById("authenticationHash").value.toString(); //this is the hash given to you to authenticate
         var secret = document.getElementById("secretHashKey").value;
         var recv_ciphertext = document.getElementById("recievedCiphertext").value; //this is the recieved ciphertext
         var authenticated = bcrypt.hash(recv_ciphertext + secret, "$2a$" + 14 + "$zXzRAU95b1dzoCjVjMIuF."); //This extra bit is that this bcrypt implementation I'm using can create a custom salt, but that doesn't matter here, since the secret key can act as a salt AND the rounds are customizable etc. etc.
         if (authenticated == authentication) {
               alert("Authenticated!")
         } else {
               alert("Authentication Failed!")
         }
}
```

Now, I do not see any issues here, but of course, anyone can create a cryptosystem that they can't break.
Here is the *sender's* side of the code:

```
function encrypt() {

...usual trusted encryption...

var secretHashKey = document.getElementById("secretHashKey").value;

document.getElementById('output').value=`
  Hash: ${bcrypt.hash(ciphertext + secretHashKey, "$2a$" + 14 + "$zXzRAU95b1dzoCjVjMIuF.")}; //the custom salt is public, anyone can know this
  Hash Method: 'default'; //just to tell the receiver that we're using the default hash method, but this is pretty useless since bcrypt speaks for itself
  Ciphertext: ${ciphertext}; //ciphertext
 `;
}
```

Finally, that's all the code. Is there anything wrong with it? I think this is a *really* straightforward implementation, but there of course could be bugs.

Comment: What's wrong is that's not what bcrypt is for, at all. You don't need a slow hash for a MAC, just use HMAC-SHA256, or use an AEAD cipher. Have you looked into using the web crypto api?

Comment: As I mentioned, I can change the hash I'm using, and I do have a sha3 library which can be used as well. I can use SHA256, so would that be better than bcrypt?

Comment: SHA256 by itself is not suitable as a MAC, it must be used with HMAC. SHA3 _can_ be used by itself, though KMAC is sometimes recommended to avoid certain mistakes. I highly recommend looking into using AES-GCM with the web crypto api instead. A quick search shows some examples [here](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#aes-gcm).

Comment: Since you mentioned that SHA3 is suitable for the MAC, a SHA3 512 hash would be much easier to implement, since some browsers do not support the web crypto api, which by extension, they do not support an AES-GCM approach. Do you recommend a SHAKE (which is in the sha3 family) or a SHA3-512 hash as you mentioned?